# A SIGSEGV signal on calling sem_open()

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

*I use follows piece of code to check how to use semaphores* :

```
char    sema_name [NAME_MAX];
sem_t   *sema_hnd = NULL;
const mode_t semprot = 0777; /*S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG ;*/

int cid = 79;


int main()
{

    sprintf(sema_name, "/StarLet-TV-CID=%d", cid);

    if ( !(sema_hnd = sem_open(sema_name, O_CREAT, semprot, cid)) )
        printf("errno=%d", errno);


    printf("sema_hnd=%#x", sema_hnd);
}
```

Getting `SIGSEGV` in the `sem_open()`, so what I do wrong?

```
root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# uname -a
Linux SysMan-Ubuntu 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's looks like that trouble in the shm-directory.c module:

```
__shm_directory (size_t *len)
{
  /* Determine where the shmfs is mounted.  */
  __libc_once (once, where_is_shmfs);

  /* If we don't know the mount points there is nothing we can do.  Ever.  */
  if (__glibc_unlikely (mountpoint.dir == NULL))
    {
      __set_errno (ENOSYS);
      return NULL;
    }

  *len = mountpoint.dirlen;
  return mountpoint.dir;
}
```

At this line "if (__glibc_unlikely (mountpoint.dir == NULL))"

Take a look to :

```
root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/home/sysman# cd /dev/shm
    root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# ll
    total 0
    drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   40 окт 13 19:17 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 3860 окт 13 19:18 ../
    root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# ls >zz.log
    root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# ll
    total 4
    drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   60 окт 13 19:19 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 3860 окт 13 19:18 ../
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root    7 окт 13 19:19 zz.log
    root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# cat zz.log
    zz.log
    root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm#


root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              990112         0    990112   0% /dev
tmpfs             204076     21896    182180  11% /run
/dev/sda1       48250196  34281344  11865744  75% /
tmpfs            1020376         4   1020372   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1020376         0   1020376   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
Downloads      976759804 802679056 174080748  83% /media/sf_Downloads
Works          976759804 802679056 174080748  83% /media/sf_Works
tmpfs             204072        12    204060   1% /run/user/122
tmpfs             204072        20    204052   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0           56618     56618         0 100% /media/sysman/VBox_GAs_5.2.18
tmpfs             204072         0    204072   0% /run/user/0
root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm#


root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm# mount | grep shm
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
root@SysMan-Ubuntu:/dev/shm#
```

Moreover, **the first run of the program was successful and the semaphore with the name 'StarLet ..." was created.** After **second** run the code is finished with SIGSEGV at sem_open(). Reboot was not help.

Comment: You get no output at all?

Comment: Just in case: This `printf("sema_hnd=%#x", sema_hnd)` invokes undefined behaviour and ought to be `printf("sema_hnd = 0x%p", (void*) sema_hnd)`.

Comment: Do you compile this code using the option `-pthread`?

Comment: program is crashed at sema_open() call. Sure, -pthread -rt keys has been included.

Comment: sem_open call :
  SHM_GET_NAME (EINVAL, SEM_FAILED, SEM_SHM_PREFIX);

Answer (score 2):

Your system seems to be missing the filesystem for named semphores:

From [`man 7 sem_overview`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html):

> **Accessing named semaphores via the filesystem**
>
> On Linux, named semaphores are created in a virtual filesystem,
>          normally mounted under */dev/shm*, with names of the form ***sem***.somename.
>          (This is the reason that semaphore names are limited to `NAME_MAX-4`
>          rather than `NAME_MAX` characters.)

Use the [`mount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) command to check if `shm` is mounted as type `tmpfs`.

The list returned by `mount` should contain an entry like:

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

And if it isn't mounted, mounting can be done by:

```
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /dev/shm -o nosuid,nodev
```

Comment: I'd think that OS library code using `SIGSEGV` as a failure mode is a bug.